# IntelliJ seems not working correctly on Ubuntu, External Libraries cannot expand?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

See this image:
[image]

Click on "External Libraries" but no respond. Using IntelliJ on Ubuntu. Click "Window" tab also no popup menu. What could be the cause? Thanks in advance!

The idea.log file is pasted here: [idea.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGlhDMyLUkJb7H0c4gvtvP50hnDt5UDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE? Do you face the same issue for all projects?

Comment: Hey, dear y.bedrov! I have added the linkage to my idea.log. Could you please diagnose it for me, please?

Comment: @y.bedrov Dear y.bedrov, have you viewed it? Could you please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: I requested access."You need access" is still shown.

Comment: @y.bedrov Can you access it now? I have also sent you an email with the log as an attachment. Have you received it?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Where is your project located (local or mount drive)? Do you face the same issue with new sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov Yes. It's a local project. And obviously its IntelliJ IDEA environment bug. Please tell me what's the cause you've found?

Comment: @y.bedrov Also you could also answer frankly by saying that IntelliJ IDEA currently doesn't support Linux platform?

Comment: IDEA supports Linux. There are some messages in log about undetected project location. Could you please try to backup and clean folders used to store settings (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and run IDE with defaults?